# Why gem5 output shows that the number of cpu cycle less than the number of instructions simulated?

Tags: gem5

[output of gem5 after run a simple spec test program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN7En.png)

I run a spec test case using gem5. It's SE model and with O3CPU. This is the command I run:

```
/gem5/build/ARM/gem5.opt --outdir=/gem5/spec2006log/m5out_ 462.libquantum-1-O3CPU /gem5/configs/example/se.py --caches --cpu-type=O3CPU --mem-size=1GB -n 1 --cmd=/benchmark/462.libquantum/exe/libquantum_ base.qemurio -o '33 5'
```

Then I saw a strange output of gem5 as the picture shows. Why does the O3CPU execute more than one instruction in a CPU cycle? Is O3cpu a superscalar CPU? I didn't see the related description in the gem5 document and it confuse me very much.
I need help, thank a lot!

Comment: `MinorCPU` and `(Deriv)O3CPU` ("O3" = out-of-order) are both superscalar processors, so are both able to achieve IPCs greater than 1.